# SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 3

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012, service-pack

Our DBA wants to apply Service Pack 3 on SQL Server 2012, has anyone installed SQL Server 2012 SP3 on a SharePoint 2013 farm?

Any catch outs?

Any articles that show it is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the requirement, SharePoint 2013 with SP1 is fully supported with Sql Server 2012 SP3.

If you are using the PowerPivot then this SP will give you more flexibility.

If you apply upgrade in a planned way then no issue at all.

- Schedule the Downtime for you SharePoint
- Start from lower farm and test it.
- Perform a full backup of you SQL database( in case of corruption you can recover it)
- I would stop the SharePoint during the SQL upgrade process( to avoid any connection to SQL from SharePoint which cause corruption.). When i did last year we shut down the SharePoint for couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

We've not seen any issues with SP3 for SQL 2012 with SharePoint 2013, although I'm struggling to find an article that explicitly states that it's supported!

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4 lists SQL Server 2012 as a minimum software requirement.